# calculus new method

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

could you help me to find to find a function $f(x)$ so that
$$
\frac{d f(x+1)}{d x}+\frac{d f(x+2)}{dx}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+1)^3}}?
$$

Comment: With $\partial x^1$, do you mean that there are other variables $x^2,x^3$ etc. or do you mean the first derivative with respect to $x$?

Comment: is f(x) only one variable

Comment: What's the range of $x$ values for which you want a solution? Perhaps $x \ge 0$?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Let us make a guess, that our function is $-2x^{-1/2}$. Evaluate the left-hand side.

We get $(x+1)^{-3/2}+ (x+2)^{-3/2}$. Close, but not quite close enough.

But what about if we add the term $2(x+1)^{-1/2}$? Then when we evaluate the left-hand side, we get 
$$(x+1)^{-3/2}+(x+2)^{-3/2}-(x+2)^{-3/2}-(x+3)^{-3/2}.$$
Nice cancellation. Getting warmer!
What about if we add the term $-2(x+2)^{-1/2}$?  Continue.

For positive $x$, we end up with the (conditionally) convergent series
$$f(x)=-2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}} +\frac{1}{\sqrt{2+x}} -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3+x}}+\cdots\right).$$

The function $f(x)$ has a "closed" form, but not in terms of the usual elementary functions.

**Remark:** If we take our troubles to infinity, they may go away.

Comment: well done but your f(x) gives 0 when you substitute in $$F'(s+1)+F'(s+2)$$ .

Comment: i believe that we actually get $(x+1)^{-3/2}$. The first term survives the collapsing.

Comment: As you can see if you have some familiarity with them, we get a zeta-function. My solution is not exactly what you write, the sum starts at $n=0$, and the power of $-1$ is $(-1)^{n+1}$. That's because of the $f'(x+1)+f'(x+2)$.

Comment: sorry my last message ,now I has time to write more properly, your solution is f(x)==$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } -\frac{2 (-1)^n}{\sqrt{n+x}}$$ and $$ \left(F'(x+1)+F'(x+2)=0\right) \left(F(x)\text{:=}\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } -\frac{2 (-1)^n}{\sqrt{n+x}}\right)$$ as you can see, with your help i get a solution$$\frac{\zeta \left(\frac{3}{2},\frac{x+1}{2}\right)-\zeta \left(\frac{3}{2},\frac{x+3}{2}\right)}{2 \sqrt{2}}$$ which is correct check it in matlab thanks anyway.